# Using InfoPath to report on SharePOint library data

Tags: infopath

In our organization, the reporting function on the SharePoint 2010 server farm is NOT turned on. 
We have InfoPath forms that gather lots of info from a user and it goes to a form library and we publish all data from form as column in the library.
I would like to create an InfoPath form to query the data in the library to produce monthly reports.
can this be done? 
Obviously, the reporting function would be ideal and then use report builder tool, but that isn't an option at the moment.